# JQuery - .each() Fails To Change Class Of Selected Elements

Tags: jquery, each

As I'm iterating through a set of HTML elements passed into a function, I'm trying to set a class on certain elements (rel), depending upon a test.  After I set the class, the content I'm returning appears not to have been changed.  I'm sure there's a basic disconnect in my logic - any guidance on why my changes don't appear?

this JSFiddle shows it in (in)action: http://jsfiddle.net/spRvh/3/

HTML

```
<ul> 
      <li title = "ID: 3 " id = "ID1" rel = "departmentgroup" class = "leaf"> 
        <a href = "#" class = "departmentgroup" rel = "15000_3_16010_relationship_Department-Path"> 
            <ins class = "departmentgroup"> & nbsp; </ins>
            Floating
        </a> 
      </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
newData = $.trim(data);
$.each($(newData).find("a"), function (i, item) {
    thisrel = $(item).attr("rel");
    if ($('#' + thisrel).length > 0) {
        $(item).children().removeClass().addClass('tick');
    }
  });
$.each($(newData).find("a"), function (x, curr) {
    alert($(curr).children().attr("class")); // no changes evident
});
```

Comment: Do you have an element with the ID `#15000_3_16010_relationship_Department-Path` ?

Comment: @adeneo - yes, the element in question exists... and I had an alert placed in the code that set the class which confirmed the match was made... but still no class change when iterating through newData after supposedly having set the "ins" appropriately

Comment: I threw together this makeshift JSFiddle, but it works for me. The `div` would be red if its class wasn't changed: http://jsfiddle.net/4dLdx/

Comment: @NateKibler - I put one together too, to show that it doesn't work for me... Apart from the fact that I'm calling this as a function and passing in "data", I don't see a difference. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/spRvh/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this issue because you're passing in a HTLM string, not the actual DOM nodes, so you're changing classes on a completely unrelated piece of HTML that has nothing to do with the actual nodes in the document.

To fix it, change

```
fixit($("#testit").html());
```

to

```
fixit($("#testit"));
```

and modify the function to work with the DOM, not a string you pass in

```
function fixit(data) {
    $.each(data.find("a"), function (i, item) {
        var thisrel = $(item).attr("rel");
        if ( $('#' + thisrel).length > 0 ) {
            $(item).children().removeClass().addClass('tick');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: absolutely correct... thanks, I  knew it must have been something quite obvious.  Your suggestion solved my issue.